# Applescript Printer Alerts via iMessage

Tags: ios, applescript, automator, printing, sms

Is there a way to send an SMS via Applescript/Automator in either of these scenarios:

- When a low printer ink alert occurs ("Cyan is at or below 10%)
- With the periodic status of ink levels ("Cyan=10%, Magenta=50%, etc. every hour)

I'm building an automated photo printing station with multiple printers and it would be helpful to incorporate this flow to keep an eye on ink levels.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to send SMS messages, you need access to an SMS gateway service. So what kind of account would you use to send the messages from?

Comment: Actually I would probably use iMessage/Messenger

Comment: So you want to send notifications via a Messages account already on your Mac? You may want to edit your question and replace SMS with iMessage. The two technologies seem identical, but rely entirely on different modes of transportation.

Comment: Hi medbot - that's correct. The machine has an iCloud account associated with it. I would like it to iMessage another account automatically with either periodical ink status counts or when a low ink notification happens. Thanks.